# DownloadData() produces HTML different from the browser

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I'm trying to download the source HTML of a website using the `WebClient.DownloadData()` method.

My method is supposed to give me the source:

```
public string GetSite(string URL)
    {
        Uri Site = new Uri(URL);
        byte[] lol = Client.DownloadData(Site);
        SiteSource = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(lol);
        return SiteSource;                    
    }
```

I've TRIPLE checked and when I write the **exact same url** of the URL parameter I send this method, my programs downloads something else entirely.

Pressing ctrl+U in firefox to see the source code shows me what I need to see (*again, simple HTML*), but in my software I see something entirely different.

What gives?

**FOR CLARITY**:

Imagine in Firefox you write www.google.com, viewing the source in Firefox you see:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body> 
       <h1>Hello!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

But if I were to use the `DownloadData` method for **the exact same URL**, my program would download a source code like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body> 
       <h1>Bonjour!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What **does** it download?  It's got to be from somewhere - tracking it down will give you a clue as to what's going on.  How about giving us a real-life example?

Comment: I'm kind of weary of posting the link here. Maybe people will throw a bitch fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site may be doing browser detection, and serving up different HTML depending on whether it perceives the client to be Firefox, IE, a Web crawler, etc.

Comment: Setting your User Agent to match that of Firefox's would circumvent it.

Comment: Specifically, webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", ...).  See the WebClient.Headers docs in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The site might use cookies that are set in Firefox, the User-Agent header or other HTTP headers to decide what content should be sent to you.

Since your C# program sends different data than Firefox the site might send different content.